# After redirect I want my url as it was typed

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-routing

Currently I have subdomain.mydomain.com, which redirects to mydomain.com/subdomain(I am using a PHP - codeigniter framework).

But all I want is after redirection url should remain subdomain.mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com/subdomain.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Use AJAX to load content of `mydomain.com/subdomain` to `subdomain.mydomain.com`

Comment: If you want the URL to remain the same, don't do a redirect!

Answer (score 1):

if you like to keep it pure html + php, i suggest you look into the iframe tag from html.
it is basically a browser window within your current browser window. Set the iframe to cover up 100% of your current browser window and set it's url to mydomain.com/subdomain.

what you'll see is that it's displaying content from mydomain.com/subdomain but your url field in your main browser is still saying subdomain.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in the routes.php file(present in config folder):

```
$route['mydomain.com/subdomain'] = "subdomain.mydomain.com";
```

Basically it's logic is

```
$route['route_you_want_to_show'] = "current_route";
```

But mind well in codeigniter routes are formed from the redirection of code to controller and its methods.

Comment: Hi Dash, you get it wrong. I want to show "subdomain.mydomain.com" and current route is mydomain.com/subdomain. I have already tried it.